# Ruby-Audio - "The specified module could not be found..."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, audio, rubygems

I've installed the ruby-audio-1.6.1 gem and I've added it to my Gemfile for my rails project however when trying to start up the server I'm getting:

> C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/ruby-audio-1.6.1/lib/ruby-audio.rb:6:in
>   `require': 126: The specified module could not be found.
>   - C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.1.0/ruby-audio-1.6.1/rubyaudio_ext.so
>   (LoadError)
>           from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/ruby-audio-1.6.1/lib/ruby-audio.rb:6:in`
>   rescue in '
>           from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/ruby-audio-1.6.1/lib/ruby-audio.rb:1:in
>   `<top (required)>'
>           from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.8/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in`
>   require'
>           from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.8/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in
>   `block (2 levels) in require'
>           from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.8/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in`
>   each'
>           from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.8/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in
>   `block in require'
>           from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.8/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in`
>   each'
>           from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.8/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in
>   `require'
>           from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.8/lib/bundler.rb:134:in`
>   require'
>           from E:/Development/mixer/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
>           from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:79:in`
>   require'
>           from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:79:in
>   `block inserver'
>           from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in`
>   tap'
>           from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in
>   `server'
>           from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in`
>   run_command!'
>           from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in
>   `<top (required)>'
>           from bin/rails:4:in`require'
>           from bin/rails:4:in `'

I've been digging around and can't find much, I've ensured that libsndfile is installed correctly so the initial gem install went just fine, it's now just erroring out at this point. I've checked the file actually exists in that location and it does some I'm a bit stumped as to what could be going wrong.

Comment: have you required it in the file you're using?

Comment: @dax I'm not even using it yet, I've just added it to my Gemfile and tried to run the server to check that. I've not attempt to use it anywhere yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Gemfile, try marking it as require false:

```
gem 'ruby-audio', require: false
```

Try starting the server, and post the results in your question.

You may also want to try a newer gem because the ruby-audio gem is quite old.

The `sndfile` gem is similar and newer: https://github.com/ronen/sndfile

Comment: That worked but I'm going to give the sndfile gem a crack since I'd not come across it before! Thanks a lot